# Trigger thickbox from flash

Tags: flash, triggers, thickbox

i wonder if somebody knows how to trigger thickbox from onRelease() event in flash.

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ActionScript3 [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class to call a JavaScript function on your HTML page like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("your_javascript_function()");
```

Your JavaScript calls, must be in quotes.

I haven't used ThickBox, but I am sure you use JavaScript to interact with it.

**EDIT***

Just looked at the Thickbox API and i think your JavaScript call will look something like this:

```
tb_show("","mycontent.html?height=500&width=400","");
```

Got that code from [here](http://hobione.wordpress.com/2007/12/28/jquery-thickbox/). I think the tricky thing will be overlaying HTML content on-top of Flash content. There are a few forum posts about this around. I will edit my answer if I come across one with a good solution.

Comment: thank you! that solved my problem, and about the layering issue, in most of the cases the problem is solved adding as flash parameter "wmode=transparent".

thanks!!